# KMS permissions for encrypted CloudWatch LogGroups with AWS Systems Session Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, aws-ssm

I've set up a CMK (Custom Managed Key) to encrypt LogGroups with AWS Systems Session Manager:

1. First, permissions for "key administrators" and "key users/roles" are added in the KMS console.
2. Next, the CMK is attached in AWS Systems Manager Session Manager Preferences to the LogGroup as shown in this image:

[image]

**Error:**

The specified KMS key does not exist or is not allowed to be used with LogGroup 'arn:aws:logs:my_region:my_account_id:log-group:/SSM'

The key must exist because it's used to encrypt the Sessions and is just not decrypting LogGroups properly, but it is linked to the LogGroup and the user has permission. What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to **replicate your issue**.

My session manger **settings**:

[image]

The CloudWatch log group has been **encrypted** using CLI:

```
{
    "logGroups": [
        {
            "logGroupName": "SSM",
            "creationTime": 1593579430258,
            "metricFilterCount": 0,
            "arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:xxxxx:log-group:SSM:*",
            "storedBytes": 0,
            "kmsKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:key/xxxx-9500-xxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

After launching the session manger I can get confirmation that it is encrypted:

[image]

Based on this verification, the only thing required to make it work was setting KMS key policies. I added the following to my KMS (`SSMRole` is instance role, the other entries should be self-explenatory):

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt*",
        "kms:Decrypt*",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:Describe*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
            "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:logs:arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:xxxxx:log-group:SSM"
        }
    }
},    
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "ssm.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt*",
        "kms:Decrypt*",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:Describe*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"            
}, 
{
    "Effect": "Allow",    
    "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt*",
        "kms:Decrypt*",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:Describe*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/SSMRole"
    }      
}
```

Comment: Great success, Marcin.  Appreciate the thorough explanation, helps me understand policy usage much better.

Comment: @ForeverLearningAndCoding No problem. These policies could be probably made better by following the "least privileged" criteria, but its good start for future modifications.

Comment: Some relevant documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/encrypt-log-data-kms.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is mentioned above, make sure that your task role has the permission logs:DescribeLogGroups.

If this permission is not available SSM will also trigger the same error (We couldn't start the session because encryption is not set up on the selected CloudWatch Logs log group. Either encrypt the log group or choose an option to enable logging without encryption.)

Next to that the task role needs permissions to       logs:CreateLogStream & logs:PutLogEvents

Because it needs to verify the log group and see if it really has KMS enabled.

According to the docs these two kms: calls should cover the permissions:

```
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
    ]
    resources = [
      var.ssm_kms_key_id
    ]
  }
```

PS, you can use Cloudtrial to debug these internal AWS issues.